# How to return ISO.DATE_TIME formatted value from variable defined as java.sql.Timestamp using Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

If I want to persist into database a date as a timestamp I have to define the entity class using the java.sql.Timestamp type for the date variable as shown below.

But doing so result in the controller returning an epoch time format in the json message sent back to the browser.

If I want it in the format of yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z' in the json message sent back to the browser, how can I do this?  I tried using the @DateTimeFormat annotation on the entity class's date variable but it doesn't make any differences.

```
@Entity
public  class Party implements Serializable {

    @Column(nullable=false)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL},targetEntity=Organizer.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="id_Organizer",referencedColumnName="id",nullable=false,updatable=false)
    private Organizer id_Organizer;

    @Column(name="startDate")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
    private Timestamp start;
}
```

Controller looks like this

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/createtestarray", method=RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Party> createParty(Model model) {
        List<Party> PartyList = new ArrayList<>();
        Party Party = Generator.createParty();
        PartyList.add(Party);
        return PartyList;
    }
```

Comment: You should use Jackson annotation to control how the value is serialized to JSON. Take a look at `@JsonFormat` annotation described here: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQDateHandling . But there might be some issues with javax.sql.Timestamp handling, which is also described in the above link. If you run into any issues try mapping your date to util.Timestamp or util.Date ...

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt Thanks.  This works.  I'll post the complete answer below as I can't post code in comments.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually 2 ways of doing this.

**Method 1**

Annotate with @JsonFormat as suggested and show below for the fields wanted to be printed in a specific format.

```
@Column(name = "startDate")
@Basic
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
private Timestamp start;
```

**Method 2**

Customize the getters to return a String value formatted in the format wanted, rather than using the default ones which returns Timestamp.